ipmitool packets going out over unexpected NIC on bridged interface
After changing subnets for a lan/wan connected NIC (connection 1), the  ipmitool over our management network (connection 2) fails to work. It is setup on a different interface whose configuration hasn't changed. There is a management network ethernet connection (2) and a third wired fiber connection (3) bridged on the server, for several qemu VMs running on it.
This is on a CentOS 7 server that was configured before my time.
The subnet change for the lan/wan may be only tangentially related as this was coincided with the first time we restarted networking services on the server since i began working with it.
Running tcpdump on each interface shows the ipmitool packets going out over connection 3, instead of the ethernet NIC (2), which it is bridged with.
to summarize in a hopefully less convoluted manner:

eno1 - ethernet for IPMI management network
enp33s0f1 - fiber for LAN/WAN
enp33s0f0 - fiber for old access network (remnant from when LAN/WAN connection was on different subnet)

network bridging:

eno1 and enp33s0f0 as br0 with ips:
10.10.10.1/24 (access network)
10.10.20.1/24 (IPMI management network)

enp33s0f1d1 as br1 with ip:
10.10.50.3/16 (lan/wan)
10.10.0.1 gateway


routing table:
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    425    0        0 br1
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     425    0        0 br1
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     426    0        0 br0
10.10.20.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     424    0        0 br0

To localize the issue to the server, I moved the management network ethernet cable from the server to a laptop, set the laptop ip as 10.10.20.1, and was able to use ipmitool successfully for machines on 10.10.20.0/24.
Regarding the subnet change: enp33s0f1d1 was on 10.70.10.0/16 before, at which time we were able to manage other servers on the management network 10.10.20.0/24 using ipmitool without an issue.
After changing br1 to 10.10.50.3 and restarting the network services, ipmitool no longer works.
tcp dump details: ran tcpdump -i [interface] dst 10.10.20.53 on eno1, enp33s0f0, and enp33s0f1d1 while trying to initiate an ipmi connection to 10.10.20.53. all packets were sent out over enp33s0f0, when they should be going out over eno1.
I think we are overlooking something simple, but I'm confused by the bridging and routing. Thoughts or assistance is greatly appreciated.

Can you explain why the mgmt network and the "old access network" are bridged, in the first place? (And also why the "LAN/WAN" is a /16 that entirely overlaps the ipmi /24?) Once packets enter br0, the bridge decides based on its learned MACs like a switch does; what does bridge fdb show on this system? Do the bridge MAC table entries correspond to reality?

Would suggest to tidy up networking before solving any issues. With the setup as you showing it, it's bound to have strange and unexpected problems.

"...for several qemu VMs running on it."

thanks for the replies. i'm not sure why the bridging was set up this way, as it was before my time. the qemu vms on this server are a login server and the head nodes for a cluster. when this server was on the previous 10.70.10.0/16 main network, (apologies i didn't know how to describe it any better than LAN/WAN), network access was only available to the login server. the access and management networks was then set up only among the cluster machines.
regarding the /16 and /24 question, i'm not sure why 10.10.50.0/16 was chosen as the new main network subnet.

bridge fdb MAC entries do seem accurate for the system, but i will take a closer look. we are planning on rebuilding the server/VMs and networks, but trying to fix this management network issue until that plan is worked out.
